# How Can I Convert a crystal Report to Web Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, rpt

How Can I Convert a crystal Report to Web Page.I have .rpt file but it is complex to understand. Is there any way  to convert it into Web Page.

Answer (score 0):

One of the export formats supported by Crystal is HTML.
You can show that export as-is on a web server or you can embed it in an IFRame.
You can also manipulate that HTML after the export.